# Are there any differences between the programs Sandcastle Help File Builder, DoxyPress, Doxygen?

Tags: open-source, software-development, c#, .net, documentation-generator

**Questions.**

1. Are there any differences between the programs `Sandcastle Help File Builder`, `DoxyPress`, `Doxygen`?
   Or are these programs the same in functionality and you can use any of them?

**Description.**
I'm looking for a program to document the code.

Basic requirements:
- Free of charge;
- ability to work in Windows;
- ability to build UML diagrams (class diagrams) on the basis of an existing project;
- formation of documentation based on an existing project.

I assume to use one of the programs:
-   Sandcastle Help File Builder (SHFB);
-   DoxyPress;
-   Doxygen.

I skimmed through the program documentation and compiled a table.
**Table of comparisons**

```
| Candidate | Windows | UML diagram | Documentation | Free | 
| ----------| --------| ----------- | ------------- | ---- | 
| SHFB      | +       | ?           | +             | +    |
| DoxyPress | +       | ?           | +             | +    |
| Doxygen   | +       | ?           | +             | +    |
```

I expect to develop applications on `.NET`.
**Desktop(C#).**
- WinForm
- WPF

**Web(C#, JavaScript, jQuery).**
- ASP.NET;
- Blazor;